# My Header is moving

Tags: html, header

I'm trying to put a header on top of my pages. It works fine with IE 8. It moves slightly down and blocking my page content on the newest IE and apple safari. Can anyone show me what I need to put so that it is compatible for all search engines? I am PHP Including my header to all my pages. Below is my header code.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>

<body>

<div style="position: absolute; width: 1280px; height: 92px; z-index: 1; left: 1px; top: 0px" id="layer1">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 660px; height: 22px; z-index: 1; left: 238px; top: 52px" id="layer2">
        <font face="Arial">|<b>
        <a href="http://www..net/carriers/test3.php">New Cost</a> </b>| <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </b>|<b> <a href="http://www..net/carriers/newcarrier.php">New 
        Carrier</a></b> | <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </b>|<b> <a href="http://www..net/carriers/search.php">Carrier 
        Board</a></b> | </font></div>
    <p>
    <img border="0" src="/carriers/.png" margin= 0 auto width="100%" height="73"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: first check no closed '<p>', and then some html tutorial.

Comment: Tip#1: Do not use `&nbsp;` to create spacing. Use CSS.

Comment: I'd suggest you to start from learning css and html http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp. You could do some tutorials as well first

Comment: Thanks, it was the <P>. been on the PC too long today! hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the header you're talking about...

```
<img border="0" src="/carriers/echoheader.png" margin= 0 auto width="100%" height="73">
```

...it should look something like this.  I think you'll need to specify `top` and make its position `absolute`.

HTML:

```
<img class='header' />
```

CSS:

```
img.header {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   ...other styles...
}
```

Try to avoid "inline styling" - this is where you set the style of the element directly in the HTML.

It is good practice to split the style from the markup, since later, in a more complex page, you can find your way around more easily.

Comment: Actually, that was @Jirka that found that...my post was about something else.  :guilty: